# Specifying opcache.blacklist_filename from .htaccess?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Is it possible to specify a 'blacklist filename' (opcache-blacklist.txt) from .htaccess (it's a shared host). I was thinking of putting this file in the /etc/ folder, something like:

```
php_value opcache.blacklist_filename "/etc/opcache-blacklist.txt"
```

but does it have a chance to work correctly? There are no errors when I try this but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this setting:

```
php_flag opcache.enable Off
```

which appears to work (it needs to be added to a .htaccess in a directory that should be excluded from opcache).

Comment: By testing it (adding it to a .htaccess file). I wrote "appears" because it's not going to work with every hosting service (it depends on their server settings).